# Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery only fires ONCE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been racking my brain on this for a couple days. I've looked thru many different solutions, but I can't figure this out.

I have a simple form in a PHP page with a text box and search button that once the search is performed, the entered text is highlighted on the document.

**PROBLEM**:   After entering a search term in the text box and CLICKing search, all is well.  However, when I PRESS enter to search, it only fires ONCE.  Clicking search will continue to work with no issues.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var search = $('#text-search').val();
  });
  $('#text-search').keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) { //Enter key pressed
      $('#button').on(); //Trigger search button click event
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search" class="Column">
  <input name="text-search" id="text-search" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" placeholder="search & highlight">
  <input name="searchit" id="button" type="button" value="Search" onClick="highlight()">
</div>
```

HTML:

Comment: what does funtion `highlight()` do? sounds like you're overwriting the eventListener.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: highlight is not defined`, this doesn't work even once.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i've never seen this syntax to trigger a click: `$('#button').on();`.. might not do what you expect.. why not simply use `$('#button').trigger('click');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it a bit wrong and you're putting too much overhead to your code. You can achieve the same without all these `keypress` events. The `submit` event will suffice and it works flawlessly with Enter as well! However, you need to wrap your inputs with `form` element and change input type from `button` to `submit`:

```js
var searchbox = document.querySelector('#text-search')
var searchForm = document.querySelector('#search')

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  highlight(searchbox.value)
  searchForm.reset()
})

function highlight(value) {
  // do something with your value
  alert(value)
}
```

```html
<form id="search" class="Column">
  <input name="text-search" id="text-search" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" placeholder="search & highlight" />
  <input name="searchit" id="button" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Always try to use `form` element if you are getting user input. This gives you better control over input fields. Also it's semantically better than lonely inputs here and there. 
Try to avoid inline javascript in your HTML. It's just a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks!  As you can tell I'm a bit of a noob!  Although my js script was a mess, it was simply wrapping the HTML search string in FORM